# Launch emergency App/Do emergency call without screen-unlocking the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to run my application without opening the slide lock of iPhone the icon of the app should be displayed on the home wallpaper or screen. by tapping on the icon the app should run its an emergency service application. So is there any service provided by apple like calling emergency numbers without opening lock.

please suggest me

thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You have to launch all Apps through the home screen (Springboard).

There might be a way to do this when jailbreaking the device, though.

Answer (score 0):

That same functionality, which you speak of, is exactly what runs on the iPhone BEFORE it is "activated". I wonder if there is a way to use this already built in app to create what you're shooting for.