# How to display emergency contact on iPhone lock screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, lockscreen

I want to display emergency contact on lock screen of iPhone.

I've found one link to an app [Launch emergency App/Do emergency call without screen-unlocking the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348589/launch-emergency-app-do-emergency-call-without-screen-unlocking-the-iphone) but it is saying that apple will not approve this,

I saw some other applications on the AppStore:

- https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/id317958642?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ice-in-case-of-emergency/id380234187?mt=8

Can any body tell me how to do this?

Comment: they are just changing the lock screen wallpaper...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy, the ones in the app store create an image with the emergency numbers on them.
Then the user can set this image as there lockscreen. I've create an app like this.

But there is no way to make a swipe/click call the number from the lock screen.

Comment: can we make button on that image, so after clicking the button we can open our app?

Comment: No, its just an image not a view. You can not add button that work to image.

Comment: can you please tell me how to add this image on lockcreen?

Comment: You can't, the user will have to this them self via the `settings.app`

Comment: or, alternatively, play a sound track with customized disc cover with emergency number image.

Comment: can we do it programmably? .

Comment: @ShivanRaptor can you please elaborate ?

Comment: No you can not change the lock screen image programmatically, you can create the image for the user programmatically and save it to the camera roll. Then the user will have to set this image as the lock screen them selfs.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to set the Lock Screen wallpaper programmatically without jailbreak.

However, you can change the lock screen appearance by playing a sound track with customized album cover, which is the emergency image.

See [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Note that this approach may burn a lot of battery, and user cannot enjoy other music while using your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use " Emergency info screen" iPhone app. It's awesome and simple to use.

Comment: try to put more effort in your answer, like with more details and links

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the emergency info screen app and its simple and flexible to my needs.

https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/emergency-info-screen/id657684240?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8 and later you can use the **Health.app** to define your medical ID and store emergency contact details with it.  Then, from the Health.app, you can tell iOS to display this information from the emergency lock screen.

See [here](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/10/06/how-to-emergency-medical-info-ios-8-lock-screen/) for a step by step guide.